# Problems with DirectStore and baseParams in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: extjs, store, extjs3

I've got a weird problem while using the baseParams in a DirectStore of ExtJs 3.4: The baseParams are NULL, when the API call (using extdirect) is made, although the baseParams are set in the store object. I've checked this by writing the complete store object to the console during "beforeLoad". My store looks like this:

```
this.store= new Ext.data.DirectStore({
      storeId: 'HereComesTheId',
      api: {
          read: Abc.pluginName.listSomeStuff
      },
      listeners: {
          'load': function (store, records, options) {
              Ext.each(records, function (record, index, all) {
                  if (record.data.selected === true) {
                      store.fireEvent('someThingsHappened', record, index);
                      return false;
                  }
              }, this);
          }
      },
      reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(),
      remoteSort: false,
      autoLoad: true,
      baseParams:{
        'param1':  Ext.getCmp('Blub').param1,
        'param2': '123'
      },
  });
```

I've also tried to use setBaseParams(), but it doesn't work, too.
I've used stores several times before and never got a problem like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself: There was a misconfiguration of the Extdirect API, I was calling. The public function in action.class.php was set as

```
@extdirect-len 0
```

If the function expects one or more request parameters, you have to set

```
@extdirect-len 1
```

and than you have to re-generate the extdirect API. That's it